# Docker expose GRE

Tags: docker, iptables

Requirement: i need to forward all the GRE traffic to my docker container (it's a microservice analysing network traffic sent via ERSPAN)

As per https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose EXPOSE allows us to expose only tcp and udp ports.

What is the nicest way of achieving the above requirement ? I could use manually iptables to redirect that GRE traffic to the docker container, but i am very hesitant here because i do already have a lot of rules there (populated automatically). Looking for a best practices here.

Thanks,
Michal